# What are the accuracy & performance benefits of using Math.fma?

Tags: java, java-9

I only noticed today the existence of `Math.fma(a, b, c)` in Java 9, which computes `a*b + c`
(for [`double`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#fma-double-double-double-) and [`float`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#fma-float-float-float-) values).

> Returns the fused multiply add of the three arguments; that is, returns the exact product of the first two arguments summed with the third argument and then rounded once to the nearest float. The rounding is done using the round to nearest even rounding mode. In contrast, if a * b + c is evaluated as a regular floating-point expression, two rounding errors are involved, the first for the multiply operation, the second for the addition operation.

So it looks like it **improves accuracy**, by doing 1 rounding instead of 2. Is that correct? Is that conditional on CPU capabilities, or can we count on that *always*?

I'm guessing it might be implemented using special CPU instructions. Is that the case? And if so, can we expect **performance benefits** as well? I'm interested to read about actual benefits with current platforms/CPUs, but also about hypothetical future benefits.

<sub>Edit (trying to make it a bit less broad): I'm not looking after very detailed answers: yes/no to the few items to correct/confirm my understanding, plus a few pointers, would be enough for me to mark an answer as accepted. I'm really interested about both accuracy & performance aspects,
 and I think they go together...</sub>

Comment: AMD and Intel provide this as special instructions in newer chips, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set. So I guess there is a speed benefit that the JDK might make use of on such processors. But it's just a guess, and thus this is just a comment and not an answer ;-)

Comment: Adding to @cello comment, here's more information about the `fma` instruction - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply.E2.80.93add

Comment: I see 2 close votes for "too broad", and I understand, but I'm not sure how I should edit. I can remove the "other benefits?" sub-question, but I think it's reasonable to ask about accuracy & performance together... no? If I do that and change the title to "What are the accuracy & performance benefits of using `Math.fma`", would it be better? (although that assumes there are... and my question asks to confirm if those are real in the first place)

Comment: 'Can we count on that always': You can count on what it says in the Javadoc. If it was conditional on CPU capabilities the Javadoc would say so.

Comment: @EJP Yes, the Javadoc for JRE is like a contract that binds the implementor, but the text of the doc gives no detail, so I was kinda wondering if there was a catch, and the accepted answer explains what the catch is: use FMA CPU instruction if available, or fallback to `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, FMA improves accuracy for the very reason you said.

JVM uses FMA CPU instructions if available. However, FMA is not available everywhere. For example, Intel x86 CPUs before Haswell doesn't have it. It means that most Intel CPUs doesn't have FMA currently.

If CPU FMA is not available, Java uses a **very** slow solution: it performs FMA using `java.math.BigDecimal` (that is the current solution - it may change in the future, but I bet it will always be slow compared to the CPU FMA).

Comment: That, and the pointers in comments, was all I needed to understand (a little bit better) what happens in practice. Thanks!

Comment: @Eugene: you can check it out, if you decompile the class file of java.lang.Math. Or check out the [openjdk implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/9f27d513658d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java)

Comment: @Eugene: the current version is 175. It might be the case that previously, it was a simple mul and add. However, this solution doesn't guarantee the extra precision that an FMA should have.

Comment: Ah yes, very interesting: `javap -c java.lang.Math | grep -A 118 "double fma"` shows some details

Answer (score 9):

I'm on mac with the 5-th generation of i7. When I do:

```
sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
```

I can see that my cpu is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5557U CPU @ 3.10GHz` and that cu supports the `FMA`, you can see that by:

```
sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu | grep FMA
```

and as a result I get a line where this String is present. Now let's see if the JVM actually uses that.

Those methods (one for `double` and one for `float`) are annotated with `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` which means that `JIT` could replace them with actual CPU native instructions - if such are available, but this would mean that the method has to be *hot enough* - called multiple times and that's a JVM dependent thing.

I'm trying to simulate that with:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50_000; ++i) {
        result = result + mine(i);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static float mine(int x) {
    return Math.fma(x, x, x);
}
```

And I run that with:

```
 java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions  
      -XX:+PrintInlining 
      -XX:+PrintIntrinsics 
      -XX:CICompilerCount=2 
      -XX:+PrintCompilation  
      org.so/FMATest
```

There will be a bunch of lines there, but one of them is:

```
 @ 6   java.lang.Math::fma (12 bytes)   (intrinsic)
```

Which means that JVM has indeed used an intrinsic method for FMA instructions.

Comment: `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` ([JDK-8135567](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8135567) & [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate.java)) is also new in Java 9 (I had heard about it, but completely missed its presence on `Math.fma`). Thanks for bringing new details that help clear the fog.